# I must not completely understand PHP's trim() function

Tags: php, trim

I was noticing some odd results in the output of my code that I traced back to trim(). I tested and verified my result at phptester.net (please go ahead and verify). How does the following small script give the result shown?

```
$x = "d1d1d1";
define("REP", "xqzxqjb1");

echo trim($x, REP); //the output is the string 'd1d1d'

//Same result if $x = 'xqzxqjb1d1d1d1xqzxqjb1' OR $x = 'd1d1d1xqzxqjb1' OR $x = 'xqzxqjb1d1d1d1';
```

Why isn't the output 'd1d1d1' for any of these?

Comment: The second argument is a character mask: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php ; Also note, that it trims only from the **start and the end**!

Comment: REP is just the constant name...could be anything but I mean it to be "REPlacement" in my code

Comment: OK...thanks. I went to the link for the other question. That is unbelievable that PHP cannot do this w/o preg_replace()...if I could downvote PHP as a whole at this point I would ;p

Answer (score 4):

Why shouldn't it be?

> trim() - Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the **beginning and end** of a string

```
trim('d1d1d1', 'xqzxqjb1');
                  ^---remove these chars from the string
```

x,q,z,x,q,j,b - not in string, ignore
1 - present at the **END** of the string, strip it:

```
php > echo trim('d1d1d1', "xqzxqjb1");
d1d1d
     ^---see, no 1
```

Comment: OK, I thought the function trimmed the entire string from the ends, not all the characters as individual characters. How do I remove the entire string from the ends without str_replace()?

Comment: given that question, marking this whole thing as a dupe...

Answer (score 0):

Because `trim` will remove any number of *any* of those characters from the ends of a string, not (as you seem to think) the entire string.

In all cases, you end up with `d1d1d` because that's the central part of the string after stripping away the characters in `REP`.

Comment: OK...thanks. The function I need is to trim the entire substring only from the ends, which is what I thought trim() did. Is there any built-in PHP function, not str_replace(), which removes the entire string from either end of another string?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob : You are probably going to want to look in to regular expressions for this.